# Laravel detect mobile/tablet and load correct views

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have read how to add different paths or namespaces for views, but I think this is not a proper solution for me. 
What I would like to do it's to set a view base path for mobile devices and a different one for desktop devices, so in the view controllers I don't need to make any change.

That would be great to set the path in the routes file and don't touch any view controller. Any ideas for that? Maybe just Config::set the view path?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: this is a bad idea. sniffing user agent is always faulty. better is, make two subdomains,`www` and `mobile` and let user choose whatever they want. depending upon the subdomain, you can create an environment and later by just retreving the env, you can tweak whatever you need.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.. 

**Marketing message:**  "Go to our website at www.thing.com, unless you're using your mobile, in which case go to mobile.thing.com instead!"

doesn't feel right to me..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm looking at the same issue here, basically wanting to "bolt on" a directory of mobile views without messing with my controllers (if possible).

One place to do this may be the config in `app/config/views.php`:

```php
<?php

use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent as Agent;
$Agent = new Agent();
// agent detection influences the view storage path
if ($Agent->isMobile()) {
    // you're a mobile device
    $viewPath = __DIR__.'/../mobile';
} else {
    // you're a desktop device, or something similar
    $viewPath = __DIR__.'/../views';
}


return array(
    'paths' => array($viewPath),
    .....
```

seems to work, giving you a completely different directory to work from.

I'll continue to experiment, as perhaps there will be some overlap between the desktop and mobile includes, but we'll see.

PS: Agent ~= Mobile_Detect

Comment: If you always leave the views path and only include mobile on mobile you can safely fall back to the normal views when they dont need to change

Answer (score 55):

For you Laravel users in the future who are looking for a way to detect devices in the view; another option is to create a ServiceProvider - and then use `View::share()` - which will then make the device-detecting `$agent` available inside all of your views.

#### Install [Agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent)

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```

#### Create the service provider

```
php artisan make:provider AgentServiceProvider
```

#### In config/app.php

```
App\Providers\AgentServiceProvider::class,
```

#### in app/providers/AgentServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AgentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $agent = new Agent();

        View::share('agent', $agent);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

#### Then inside your views

```
@if ($agent->isMobile())
    
    Show mobile stuff...

@endif
```

## 2022 Update

It appears the Agent package has been abandoned... But, there is an alternative which is even easier to use.

https://github.com/riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect

Just install the package...

```
$ composer require riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect
```

...and start using it in Blade. No set up at all!

```php
@mobile
    Show mobile stuff...
@endmobile
```

```
@tablet
    Show tablet stuff...
@endtablet
```

```
@handheld
    Show mobile and tablet stuff...
@endhandheld
```

Note that you might have to run `php artisan view:clear` to have the new Blade directives take effect.

Comment: Agent is a comprehensive package since it is a detector of mobile, browser, name version, platform, device, robot, crawler, user language.
If you want to learn how to use you can also read this https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-detector-mobile-browser-name-version-platform-device-robot-crawler-user-language-8499bee7607c

Comment: Is Agent still in use / the best option? I've noticed it's Git build is failing, but I'm not aware of any better alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

You could create two folders `mobile`, `desktop` inside your view folder. The two folders hold the same views (only the filenames).

```
├── views
|   ├── mobile
|   |   ├── main.blade.php
|   └── desktop
|       ├── main.blade.php
```

Then inside your controller you can use the folder names to switch between the desktop and mobile views (or any other if you add more).

You only need to resolve the request's device through PHP. You can do it with this project: http://mobiledetect.net/.

Now your controller looks like:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    return View::make( ($detect->isMobile() ? 'mobile' : 'desktop') . '.your-view-name' );
}
```

It's offcourse a good idea to refactor the `($detect->isMobile() ? 'mobile' : 'desktop')` to a helper/static function. Or register it as an config item in a before route filter.

Comment: First of all, thanks! but the point to not change all the View::make along my code.

Comment: Sometimes a refactoring is necessary.. You can also extend the `View` with a class and then in the constructor handle the mobile/desktop switch. Then you only need to change all the `use`s in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment on the accepted answer (include mobile view path only on mobile and fallback to 'default' view):

```
<?php

$viewBasePath = realpath(base_path('resources/views'));

$viewsPaths = [$viewBasePath];

$agent = new Jenssegers\Agent\Agent();

if ($agent->isMobile()) {
    array_unshift($viewsPaths, $viewBasePath.'/mobile');
}

return [
    'paths' => $viewsPaths
    ...
```

This way you only override what you need. This may come in handy for emails and when you have several partial views that have the same html regardless of device category.

Note: Usage in controller doesn't change.

Example views:

```
├── views
|   ├── home.blade.php
|   ├── posts.blade.php
|   ├── post.blade.php
|   ├── emails
|   |   └── subscription.blade.php
|   └── partials
|   |   ├── posts-popular.blade.php
|   |   ├── banner-ad.blade.php
|   |   ├── post-comment.blade.php
|   ├── mobile
|   |   ├── home.blade.php
|   |   ├── partials
|   |       └── posts-popular.blade.php
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using [mobile detect class](http://mobiledetect.net/)

On root path run: `composer require mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib`

So depending on where you want to make your decision: `your-app/views/your-view.blade.php` or `your-app/routes/web.php`:

```
//include the file
use Detection\MobileDetect as MobileDetect;

//instance it
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (less tablets)
if ( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {
  echo "is mobile, do something";
}

// Any tablet device
elseif( $detect->isTablet() ){
  echo "is tablet, do something";
}

// Desktop device
else {
  echo "is desktop, do something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$agent = new Jenssegers\Agent\Agent();

$view = ($agent->isMobile()) ? "views_mobile" : "views";

$viewBasePath = realpath(base_path("resources/{$view}"));

return [
'paths' => $viewBasePath