# Laravel Mobile Support

Tags: php, mobile, laravel

I'm adding a mobile-friendly website to my laravel app (not responsive, yet a whole different website), so I added the following code to /app/config/views.php

```
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent as Agent;
$Agent = new Agent();
// agent detection influences the view storage path
if ($Agent->isMobile()) {
    $viewPath = __DIR__.'/../views/mobile';
} else {
    $viewPath = __DIR__.'/../views';
}
```

And that works great. The problem is, that I'm trying to send an email and laravel expects the email's view file also to be under `/views/mobile` directory, is there any way I can tell emails to still always load from `/views/` and not `/views/mobile`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a namespace to the views. This allows you to pull out the email views within both of your view folders and put them into a folder of their own.

This can be done like so;

```
View::addNamespace('email', '/path/to/email/views/folder');
```

This line can be put within your `/app/config/views.php` or where ever you please. And you can simply do this to access the view with this view string `'email::message'`

Comment: Hmm sounds reasonable yet I can't implement it, something breaks the code. see line #22 at http://pastebin.com/H2d0sszS

Comment: Try moving this line to `app/start/global.php` as there is nothing with the line itself. As that is where i put my own.

Comment: Did that already, that caused something even worse: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException --> Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception`

Comment: And that suddenly happens in
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`

Comment: Once you put it in `app/start/global.php` did you change the path just incase the directory does not exist?

Comment: Not sure i'm getting you, see http://oi58.tinypic.com/2a8hhu0.jpg hope it clears things a bit ;-/

Comment: Don't worry, your path was right... I really don't know, that line is correct. If you remove the line everything works?

Comment: An alternative to namespacing the views is to add mobile path only on mobile so the view falls back to the 'default' view. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779088/laravel-detect-mobile-tablet-and-load-correct-views/38885229#38885229