# Laravel change view root path from middleware

Tags: php, laravel

```
//middleware
if ( Helpers::isMobile() ) {
     //how to change view path root here, from views -> views/mobile
}

//desktop layout
/views/index.blade.php

//mobile layout
/views/mobile/index.blade.php
```

I have a website required to change views root path when it detects mobile phone.

1. I have mobile phone detection function inside of Helpers
2. I wish to run this inside of middleware
3. is that possible to disable this middleware from config? (config/setting.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779088/laravel-detect-mobile-tablet-and-load-correct-views/25998165

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel detect mobile/tablet and load correct views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779088/laravel-detect-mobile-tablet-and-load-correct-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the path at runtime you have to create a new instance of the `FileViewFinder`.

you can use this code

```
$finder = new \Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder(app()['files'], array(app_path().'/your path'));
View::setFinder($finder);
```

or you can add new location to your view folder using this code

```
\View::addLocation('location to your view folder')
```